# Microservices interdependency

Tags: microservices

One of the benefits of Microservice architecture is one can scale heavily used parts of the application without scaling the other parts. This supposedly provides benefits around cost.

However, my question is, if a heavily used microservice is dependent on other microservice to do it's work wouldn't you have to scale the other services as well seemingly defeating the purpose.  If a microservice is calling other micro service at real time to do it's job, does it mean that Micro service boundaries are not established correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There's no rule of thumb for that.

Scaling usually depends on some metrics and when some thresholds are reached then new instances are created. Same goes for the case when they are not needed anymore.

Some services are doing simple, fast tasks, like taking an input and writing it to the database and others may be longer running task which can take any amount of time.

If a service that needs scale is calling a service that can easily handle heavy loads in a reliable way then there is no need to scale that service.

That idea behind scaling is to scale up when needed in order to support the loads and then scale down whenever loads get in the regular metrics ranges in order to reduce the costs.

Comment: But you would agree that you would have to scale other parts of the system/application as well when you have interdependencies.

Comment: I will scale it depending on the load and not the emitter system. In an orchestration system like Kubernetes you don't need to look at the emitters in order to determine the number of callers. Kubernetes just looks at the pods CPU/RAM and says "is it higher than X?" If yes then scale up. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/ So the answer to your question is: if caller system scales up then the receivers will scale up only if necessary

Comment: But if microservice needs 15 microservice to do its work, than should it even be a microservice like that?  I would think combining them into a single asset may be a better choice. Would you agree?

Comment: There are many things to consider. You lose many advantages of monolithic architecture when you move to microservices. Like a wise man said, microservices only "buy you options" (potential solutions which you will have to evaluate and implement by yourself). They do no solve your problem. What I would do is to start with the single service and only then, after I identified the problems, I would consider splitting it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two topics to discuss here.
First is that usually, it is not a good practice to communicate synchronously two microservices because you are coupling them in time, I mean, one service has to wait for the other to finish its task. So normally it is a better approach to use some message queue to decouple the producer and consumer, this way the load of one service doesn't affect the other.

However, there are situations in which it is necessary to do synchronous communication between two services, but it doesn't mean necessarily that both have to scale the same way, for example: if a service has to make several calls to other services, queries to database, or other kind of heavy computational tasks, and one of the service called only do an array sorting, probably the first service has to scale much more than the second in order to process the same number of request because the threads in the first service will be occupied longer time than the second